# Combining P values using Fisher method matlab?

Tags: matlab, probability, static-analysis

After doing CDF I received following values of `P` (Sample of them)

```
[0.43   0.12    0.0021  0.05    0.017   0.001   0.025   0.038 0.35  0.29]
```

I want to combine my `P` values with the help of [Fisher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_method) method and get the output in the following way:

Select first 3 `P` values and combines them and get result from this (using fisher method). For example, my first combine `P` value would be : `0.43 ,0.12 0.0021` and my next `P` combine value would be `0.12, 0.0021 ,0.05` and so on.

Can anyone tell me how we can apply Fisher method using MATLAB for this problem?
I wasn't able to find any solution using MATLAB.

Fisher's method combines extreme value probabilities from each test, commonly known as "p-values", into one test statistic (X2) using the formula :

[documents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUABW.png) tells about fisher method and I marked in circle the formula which can be used for combining the p value via using fisher method please have a look :)

where pi is the p-value for the ith hypothesis test. When the p-values tend to be small, the test statistic X2 will be large, which suggests that the null hypotheses are not true for every test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a Fisher's combined probability test built in MATLAB, but it shouldn't be hard to implement it:

```
P = [0.43 0.12 0.0021 0.05 0.017 0.001 0.025 0.038 0.35 0.29];
k = length(P);
```

first we will make a helper matrix that sum the elements in P as we want:

```
% the following matrix is used to sun each n elements in a row:
n = 3;
summer = diag(ones(k,1));
for d = 1:n-1
    summer = summer + diag(ones(k-d,1),-d);
end
```

if we run `P*summer`, we get:

```
ans =
  Columns 1 through 6
       0.5521       0.1721       0.0691        0.068        0.043        0.064
  Columns 7 through 10
        0.413        0.678         0.64         0.29
```

Next, we compute the statistic by first taking the ln of all `P` and than sum them in 3's (and multiply by `-2`):

```
% compute the combine fisher statistic:
X = -2.*log(P(:).')*summer;
```

the result:

```
X =
  Columns 1 through 6
        18.26       22.564       26.472       27.956       29.342       27.734
  Columns 7 through 10
       16.018       11.116       4.5754       2.4757
```

Finally we compute the p-values from a chi-square distribution with `2*3 = 6` df:

```
% get the p-values for all combinations:
p_vals = chi2cdf(X(1:end-n+1),6,'upper');
```

And we get:

```
p_vals =
  Columns 1 through 6
     0.005614   0.00095661   0.00018177    9.577e-05   5.2399e-05   0.00010546
  Columns 7 through 8
     0.013659     0.084865
```

Comment: yes there is a Fisher method and I want to use that one. I have given more information about fisher method and link please have a look and give answer if possible accordingly :)

Comment: I read your link, and implemented what is written there. I didn't say there is no "Fisher method", but that I don't know of a built in function for that. If you know there is, post a link the the documentation of it. Please, go over the answer, ask for what is not clear, and see if it meets your needs. My note in the end is just for extra checking.

Comment: That's what I said, and this is why I wrote you the code for this test in the answer.

Comment: Yes. Keep in mind that it will only sum 3 `p`s every time. If you want to vary this feature, then let me know and I'll edit the answer.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many p-values you have in total, just how many you want to group into one test. You said you want to select 3 p-values each time, so that's what the code does (with the `summer` matrix). If you want to group a different number of values, you need to make a little change.

Comment: Is your `p` vector is row or column vector? In the code above only row vector will fit. Try changing it to `X = -2.*log(P(:).')*summer;` and see if it solves the problem. When I'll be again near MATLAB I'll edit it to fin any vector.

Comment: @AnkitaDebnath see my edit for grouping `n` elements in a row from the vector.