# Fisher test for a given large sets of 'p' values using matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, probability-density

The following problem is the extension of [This problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39128063/combining-p-values-using-fisher-method-matlab)

I have written the following codes :

```
load y; P = y;k = length(P);
```

% the following matrix is used to sum each 'n' elements in a row:

```
   `n = 2;                %For sum of n elements in a row 
    summer = diag(ones(k,1)); 
     for d = 1:n-1
          summer = summer + diag(ones(k-d,1),-d);
    end
      X = -2.*log(P(:).')*summer;`
```

The value of X I am getting is 'NAN' values for all given P datasets array(of size 200x1) but when I am testing this with say 10 values of P then it is working very fine and not giving me any 'NAN' values.Can anyone help me why I am not getting values for large datasets while for small number it is working...??

Answer (score 0):

There are probably -Inf, Inf, or NaN values in your P vector to begin with. Based on the arithmetic operations being done this seems to be the only possible source of NaN values resulting in X

Comment: Some of the value of P is zero but no infinity or NAN.